# Show that $[a, m] = m$ if and only if $a$ divides $m$, where $[a, m] = \mathrm{lcm}(a,m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $[a, m] = m$ if and only if $a$ divides $m$, where $[a, m] = \mathrm{lcm}(a,m)$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

If $[a,m]=m$, then $a$ must divide $m$ since by definition, $[a,m]=m$ is a multiple of $a$.

Now, suppose that $a$ divides $m$. It follows that $m$ is a multiple of $a$. However, $m$ is also the lowest positive multiple of $m$.  So, it must be the case that $m$ is the least common multiple of $a$ and $m$. Thus, $[a,m]=m$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a\mid m$. Then $(a,m)=a$. Since $(a,m)[a,m]=am$, it follows $[a,m]=m$.

Now suppose $[a,m]=m$. Then $(a,m)=a$. But $a=(m,a)\mid m$